# MySQL Find Rows Which Include Same String But Not Fully

Tags: mysql, parameters, duplicates, row

I have records like these:

`id  line
1   node_id 588772
2   node_id 215698
3   node_id 546464
4   node_id 878888
5   access 787888
6   node_id 778787
7   access 111222
..................`

So, i need to return value something like that:

`node_id ****
access ****`

I mean node_id same but after that comes parameter.

stars coresponds to it is parameter.

Comment: It's not clear what your output should look like.

Comment: Purpose find the word which taken parameter, for this example: node_id and access

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking for but maybe this

```
select substring_index(line,' ',1) line,group_concat(substring_index(line,' ',-1)) parameters
from t
group by substring_index(line,' ',1);

+---------+------------------------------------+
| line    | parameters                         |
+---------+------------------------------------+
| access  | 787888,111222                      |
| node_id | 588772,215698,546464,878888,778787 |
+---------+------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.024 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any rows where the number is identical for node_id and access_id

So i added them so that you can see how the algorithm works

It shows all rows where node_id and access_id have the same number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `line` VARCHAR(14)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `line`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'node_id 588772'),
>   ('2', 'node_id 215698'),
>   ('3', 'node_id 546464'),
>   ('4', 'node_id 878888'),
>   ('5', 'access 787888'),
>   ('6', 'node_id 778787'),
>   ('7', 'access 111222'),
>   ('8', 'node_id 787888'),
>   ('9', 'node_id 111222');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`line`,' ',-1) aS linenum  FROM table1 
> GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`line`,' ',-1) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
> ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`line`,' ',-1) = t2.linenum
> ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`line`,' ',-1)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | line          
> -: | :-------------
>  7 | access 111222 
>  9 | node_id 111222
>  5 | access 787888 
>  8 | node_id 787888
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bea3e68768accb428fa6bff4f80192a5)*

Comment: Important thing is find parts of the first parts, because they take parameters, i mean first parts same but the parametres can be change, determine node_id and access our purpose, thank you for your answer, i understand it ;)

Comment: it is quite hard t understand completely, but that seems to be the best approach. mysql isn't t really cut out for this. especially when the patternget more complivcated, so you should thnik about, doing it in anther language.